# Chrome and Safari splits the screen when viewing SVG content, how to disable?

Tags: cross-browser, svg

Here it is: http://appdist.me

On Firefox and IE it displays correctly, but not on Chrome and Safari.
I'm using *svgweb*, but still no good.

How can I get Chrome and Safari etc. to display the content the same way as Firefox and IE?

I'm not going to post any code, just view the source of the HTML. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work well in both Firefox and Chromium by setting width and height attributes on the object tags to 100% **and** setting width and height attributes of the SVG elements in keyboard-gray.svg and frame-home.svg to 100%. Check it out:

http://live.echo-flow.com/stackoverflow/appdist.me/

Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows box available to test this in IE at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much, works well on IE so no worries there. +1